# Bizarre issue when populating a list with objects in C++?

Tags: c++, list, oop

I have created a class `Patient` and I want to populate a list of `Patients` with objects which I have created via the explicit constrctor. However I get an error `Type name is not allowed` when I try to populate the `list<Patient>` using the `={}(initializer list). I would like to ask what am I doing wrong?

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
using namespace std;
class Patient {
    string name;
    string birthday;
    int visits;
    public:
    Patient(string n, string b, int v) {
        name = n;
        birthday = b;
        visits = v;
    }

};
list<Patient> sp = {
Patient a("I.Petrov", "21.12.02", 4),
Patient b("D.Stoyanov", "12.02.97", 7),
Patient c("K.Dimitrov", "07.08.90", 1)
};

int main()
{



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Patient a("I.Petrov", "21.12.02", 4)` -> `Patient ("I.Petrov", "21.12.02", 4)`, and repeat for all other `Patient`s.

Comment: also, avoid global variables

Comment: Hi, @AlgirdasPreidžius. Why are you answering in the comments section?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Because, in my opinion, it is borderline typo. And, additionally, because I was too lazy to write proper answer, instead of writing a single-line in comments :/

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Please use the answer section for writing answers, so that we can properly peer review your contribution. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

The list's initializer takes a sequence of expressions, but you've given it full variable declarations instead. That's simply not valid syntax. You can only put declarations in "free space" in a function or at namespace scope, not inside another statement (we'll ignore the joys of conditionals for the purpose of this answer).

You probably intended to create some temporaries instead:

```
list<Patient> sp = {
   Patient("I.Petrov", "21.12.02", 4),
   Patient("D.Stoyanov", "12.02.97", 7),
   Patient("K.Dimitrov", "07.08.90", 1)
};
```

But I'd write it as:

```
std::list<Patient> sp{
   {"I.Petrov",   "21.12.02", 4},
   {"D.Stoyanov", "12.02.97", 7},
   {"K.Dimitrov", "07.08.90", 1}
};
```