# Initialize a vector of objects in C++

Tags: c++, class, object, vector

my problem is the following: I have a class named City with the paramters Name, Latitude and Longitude. In my main class I want to initialize a vector with some cities.

Here is my City Header File:

```
using namespace std;

#define RADIUS 6378.137
#define PI 3.14159265358979323846


class City {

public:
City(string _name, double _latitude, double _longitude) {
    name = _name;
    longitude = _longitude * PI / 180.0;
    latitude = _latitude * PI / 180.0;
}
~City() { };

private:
double longitude;
double latitude;
string name;
double earthRadius = RADIUS;
};
```

And then there is my main class file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Route.h"

using namespace std;

vector<City> initRoute { (("Boston", 42.3601, -71.0589),
("Houston", 29.7604, -95.3698), ("Austin", 30.2672, -97.7431),
("San Francisco", 37.7749, -122.4194), ("Denver", 39.7392, -104.9903),
("Los Angeles", 34.0522, -118.2437), ("Chicago", 41.8781, -87.6298)) };

int main() {

    //for each(City city in initRoute)
        //city.printCity;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile it puts out the Error C2398:

```
Error   C2398   Element "1": Die Conversion from "double" to  "unsigned int" 
requires a restrictive conversion.
```

I have the feeling that my initialization of my vector is wrong but I dont know what to change.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: To create a `City` object use e.g. `City("Boston", 42.3601, -71.0589)`. And drop the extra pair of parentheses `()` wrapping it all.

Comment: Change your `()` into `{}`.  You need `{}` in list initialization

Comment: Very similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/52724934/3871028

Comment: One thing you can do is try figuring out how to initialize your vector with ***one*** element before complicating the issue with a whole list of elements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to specify the type of the object when you're adding it to the `vector`.

i.e.

```
vector<City> initRoute { City("Boston", 42.3601, -71.0589),
City("Houston", 29.7604, -95.3698), ... };
```

**Or**

You can use the `{}` to represent the object without explicitly mentioning the class since your vector is holding `City` objects (just like you do with `struct`s).

i.e.

```
vector<City> initRoute { {"Boston", 42.3601, -71.0589},
    {"Houston", 29.7604, -95.3698}, ... };
```